# webrick server stops after putty is disconnected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to programming and `Ruby on rails` (and `stackoverflow` as well :) . I have setup an `ubuntu` test server. I can access my ruby application over internet  which is configured on this server. I am using weBrick as webserver for my application.
I am able to start the Webrick server using command:

```
rails s -b ip address -p portnumber
```

through `putty` and then access my application over internet.

**The problem is:** when i close putty session after that I cannot access my application. the error that appears in chrome browser is

> connection refused

It appears to me that the `webserver(webrick)` shutsdown when I disconnect putty which should not happen. Please correct me where ever I am interpreting the scenario incorrectly.
Also please let me know what additional information is required to seek the resolution. Thanks

Comment: I recommend you to install a Web Server (Ngnix ou Apache) with Passenger. As you are doing, you are working on specific session. Every time you close the current session, everything goes away unless you saved it before.

Comment: Since you are new to rails, I would recommend using nginx with passenger. It's easy to install and setup and both work great. And you are right, the moment you close the connection by terminating putty, webrick shuts down. Just to try things out you could append & at the end of your command which should not shut down the process as it runs in background.

Comment: Thanks psantos and Pamio.

Comment: Pamio, appending '&' (ruby s -b ipaddress -p portnumber &)  doesn't work. Is there any other solution? Also I am doing RnD for using nginx and passenger. thanks for advice.